# Current forum software that has NNTP support and/or uses an NNTP back end?

Tags: forum, nntp

I am looking for forum software that interoperates with NNTP. This might be done by providing an NNTP interface to itself, or using an external NNTP service as its backend/post database.

Google turns up a number of lists that mostly terminate at 404s or otherwise dead software. Nothing that's still being maintained, as far as I can tell.

Open source on Linux is preferable. I don't care about the language.

Comment: Anything more forum features it must/should/could have? Price? Language preferences like PHP? On what OS does it need to be hosted?

Comment: I am guessing that the available options are limited enough that I can't be picky about any of those things. That said, open source on Linux is preferable. I don't care about language, and the specific forum feature I'm looking for is NNTP interoperation, as said.